# Where to put a new ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, binding, installation, directory

Where's the best place for a production asp.net application? I mean a place that we need less permission manipulation on folders and probably the experts choice.

under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` or `C:\inetpub` or elswhere ?

In development/test phases I usually put it under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and create a new web application without setting bindings. But on production version with binding I'm not sure where's the right place.

Comment: Using different place has it's own disadvantages like setting permissions on folder and also when migrating to a new system there's no `D:` and for the last reason I changed my behavior and started to use default `inetbub` folder.

Comment: each to their own I suppose. It's purely subjective (your point of view). From a technical perspective (as the question asked), it's very doable provided u know the pros/cons.

Comment: @Pure: What do you mean of `It's purely subjective`? (since your nickname is pure clarify the word reference please). I asked this question because of a personal experience. I changed the standard folder and there was a lot of permissions, after build batch files... and on a new system I had a lot of problem to modify batch files, setting permissions... since new machine drive letters was something else so I decided to use the standard folder and this question is asked to prevent something like my previous mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it anywhere you like, they key thing is to ensure that the app pool it is running under is set to run as a low privileged user (like NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE), then ensure that user has *Read* (and possibly *Browse* if you want it) permissions on the folder you put your web app in. Very seldom (if ever) will the user need *Write* or *Modify* permissions on the folder.

> and on a new system I had a lot of problem to modify batch files, setting permissions

Setting permissions should not be a problem, you should set the same basic permissions i mentioned above for the user you want to run the app pool as. You can use PowerShell or WMI for this, and you should use the same permissions no matter what folder you install in to.

You could always wrap all this up into an installer, then it can be as simple as hitting *Next.. Next... Finish...* in an installer wizard to set up your website on **any** machine. Doing this in an installer also gives you some certainty that nothing has been missed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have a 'Development' folder on my D: drive which is then subdivided into different categories depending on the work. I generally don't use inetpub directory and any permission issues I come across I just set directly onto the relevant folder within my own development structure.

On production environments I've used in the past, we've generally done the same thing. Mainly to help backup scenarios really, but also because there's no strict need to use the default IIS directories - you're free to structure things how you like.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I always create a new folder (in the root of a drive) called `WebSites`. I then make sure it has the appropriate permissions for the website process(es) (aka `App Pools`).

eg.

```
C:\
|_WebSites
     |_www.Foo.com
     |_www.Bah.com
```

It also makes it easier to manage because you don't have to *hunt* through the folder structures to find any/all websites.

But technically, it can be (more or less) anywhere - just needs to have the correct permissions set.

#### Bonus Answer

I also remove the Default Website from IIS .. which in effect means I can also delete `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

Comment: Do you put folders below foo.com? IIS at least doesn't like serving out of folders that end in .com for good reasons . . .

Answer (score 0):

You can put the website any where on the server hard disk, Just make sure it is a secure folder and also I recommend to don't put it in the same OS drive, in case it failed and you needed to formate it.

C:\inetpub\wwwroot and C:\inetpub are just the default places nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on how the production server is configured and how operations likes to operate over there. Typically we setup a second "data" drive on servers for a few reasons:

a) Back in the old days, there were a lot of cannonical attacks where the attacker would try to navigate from c:\inetpub to c:\winnt\cmd.exe. Putting things on a different drive prevented this sort of thing.

b) Recovery -- if the OS gets hosed, you can pretty easily reinstall/reimage or move the data disks to another box and get things stood up fast.

c) Typically is lots easier to do things like swap the non-os disk in case you need more disk space or faster disks or whatever.

Basically, off the OS drive is a good idea. Though virtualization and modern deployment tools make lots of this matter less.